# Tree Grid Save State

Tags: extjs, extwebcomponents

I am using Tree grid of extwebcomponents and provided stateful: ['width','height','collapsed'] but still my treegrid state not persist.

I am using treestore where I am making ajax call to fetch data. I have used my build (main.js) on browser and running native javascript on top of it.Am I missing something?

```
Ext.create({
fullscreen: true,
xtype: 'panel',
title :  'Title',
id:"treepanel",
renderTo: 'sencha_div',

items: [{
xtype: 'tree',
id: 'treelit',
stateful: ['width','height','collapsed'],
plugins: {treedragdrop:true,gridcellediting:true,gridfilters:true},
columns: columns,
height: 800, width: 1700,
scrollable: true,
store:store,columnLines:"true"}]
});
```

Regards

Nidhi

Comment: Maybe, you should add some code snippets or a fiddle sample https://fiddle.sencha.com/

Comment: @MuzafferGalata Added Code snippet

Comment: Try to add into grid properties; `....stateful: true, stateId: 'myTreeGridState',...` And top of the code: `Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(Ext.create('Ext.state.LocalStorageProvider'));`

Comment: @MuzafferGalata It didnt work for extweb components. I tried Ext.state.Provider.register(new Ext.state.LocalStorage); But nothing works every time store got refreshed.

Comment: Please create a real sencha fiddle sample. And let us talk over it.